# NPN Darlington circuit for 12V Diesel Glowplug

Tags: npn

I'm trying to build a very simple circuit to drive a glowplug. I am using a TIP122 NPN.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMea96.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I wanted 0.017A going through the 12V plug. I estimated no more than 0.204W. I also assumed my NPN's HFE was 1000.

To find power dissipation \$12V \times 0.017A = 0.204 W\$.

Calculated base current with

$$Ib = \dfrac{0.017}{1000} = 0.000017A$$

$$R1 = \dfrac{4V-1.4V}{0.000017A} = 152941 \Omega$$

I hooked all this up, and the NPN got pretty hot. The glowplug started to get a little hot, probably around 100F by the time the NPN was around 200F and climbing fast.

I'm very new and have been more or less dealing with NPN saturation on simple devices like LED and Fans with no issues. I have done this exact circuit with a 12V relay I pulled from a car, but I was really just experimenting here trying to learn the limitations of an NPN.

Comment: Do you want to create a constant-current circuit, essentially?

Comment: The transistor amplification factor does not reduce the power required to heat the glow plug to starting temperatures. The relay that is normally used draws little power compared to the glow plug current and has an insignificant voltage drop.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating this wrong.  You want 0.017 A going through a 1 Ohm device, so you must put 0.017 A * 1 Ohm = 0.017 V across it.  Creating that kind of current control with a non-saturated grounded emitter NPN topology is pretty difficult since the Hfe is not a tightly controlled parameter for BJTs.

The correct way to do this is to put a current limiter resistor inline with the 1 Ohm device.  Then when you saturate the device, according to the graph in the datasheet, the Vce(sat) at 0.1A will be about 0.6V, so you will have $$12 - 0.6V = 11.4V$$ across the pair.

Ohms law says you need a resistance of $$\frac{11.4V}{0.017A} = 670 Ohms$$

680 Ohms is a standard resistor value in that range and should give about 0.0168A in current.

Now on to the calculation of the base resistor.  It is typical to ensure saturation by calculating as if the Hfe = 10.  This ensures that you are fully saturating the transistor.  So for a collector current of 0.017 A, you want a base current of 1.7 mA.  The TIP122 Vbe(sat) with a collector current of 0.1A is about 1.25V so the resistor will have 4V - 1.25V = 2.75V across it.  This results in:$$\frac {2.75V}{1.7mA} ~= 1.61 kOhms$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP6p3k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Two questions here:

1. You are suggesting that I do not try to use this in the active region , correct? I only wanted to do this to see how controlling the collector current worked by controlling the base current underneath the saturation point.

2. I followed your calculations, which make sense. However, I do not understand "BJT Vce will get to about 0.3 V in saturation". Where did this .3V come from?

Comment: @caveman: The TIP122 is a darlington transistor.  The datasheet gives Vce(sat) as 2 volts at Ic = 3 Amp, Ib = 12 mA.

Comment: 1. Yes, a grounded emitter topology suffers from extreme dependence on the the hfe of the transistor for its operation.  As I said hfe is not well controlled from transistor to transistor.  They just make sure it is bigger than some specification.  When a bjt saturates, it still will have a small voltage between the collector and emitter.  
2. As Peter mentioned, the darlington has a larger Vce, so I'll fixup the solution accordingly. 0.3 is the typical value used for a standard bjt.

Comment: Sorry, I've been doing a bit of churn on the analysis.  I had assumed that the transistor was a standard bjt instead of a darlington.  But I went to the datasheet and did the analysis again with the charts given.  One other statement in general.  Darlington transistors are not usually used in the active mode anyways.  They are typically used as a large gain switch.

Comment: I very much appreciate this answer. Is there a particular place I can read what Vce represents? I think I saw this modeled before as an emitter with a resistor on it. I may be entirely wrong here...just trying to grasp what VCE is. I have interpreted VBE as a drop due to being similiar to a diode.

Comment: Vce is just the voltage from the collector to the emitter. Its exact value depends on the base current, the transistor gain, and the collector and emitter loads. BJTs, including darlingtons, are essentially current devices, not voltage, although this isn't exact. Generally, a transistor will provide a collector current equal to the gain times the base current, with some modifications for Vce. Look at a transistor data sheet. Then, the load resistors determine exactly what the voltage is.

Comment: @Parker I think you may be thinking of some small-signal equivalent circuit models.  To be honest, this is one of the things that I don't feel the internet has been effective in documenting.  If you can find an old used copy of Microelectronic Circuits by Sedra/Smith (Amazon has them for less than $30), you will learn it in great detail.  It is actually pretty readable if you are motivated.  Play with a free spice simulator (LTSpice from Linear Technology is a good one) as you go through it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you simply want to drive your glowplug.

By the circuit you are showing you would need about 12A through the 1 Ohm resistor for a fully-on driver.

If you assume a transistor gain of 250 the collector current vs. the base current dictates you need 12A/250=48mA flowing into the base of the transistor.

At 4V driving signal and assuming 0.85V Vbe drop, you need a base resistor of (4V-0.85V)/0.048mA ~ 65 Ohm

You stated the transistor is actually a darlington type. This means that when fully ON, the collector~emiter voltage drop is about 1V when fully ON. This means that out of 12V, the glowplug will only see 11V, the remaining voltage will be dropped on the transistor.

Considering all this, the powers will be:

P(battery)=12V*11A=132W

P(R1)=151mW

P(glow)=11V*11A=121W

P(transistor)=1V*11A=11W (HOT!)

**You have to cool the transistor. the TO-220 package for TIP120 is NOT able to handle 11W of power with no heatsink. You will need a big one.**

If you need to adjust the power, you should do it with PWM. This means quickly turning ON and OFF the transistor by cycling the input signal 0->4->0. But you have to do this quickly, probably in the kHz region.

If you plan to play with the glow current by varying the current through the glowplug in a linear fashion, the maximum power dissipation can be calculated by the max. power theorem, which states the maximum power dissipated in the transistor will occur when the impedance of the transistor matches the impedance of the glowplug.

**In this case the max. power heating the transistor equals 36W (same power is also dissipated on the glowplug). This would require a massive heatsink. It's a waste, so don't do it.**

Use a logic level mosfet and PWM it. this will do the trick, but you will have to include a diode (anode to collector, kathode to 12V) as a glowplug kicks back some voltage when you turn it off quickly.

All this is valid assuming you want to turn the glowplug fully ON. If you don't, the same principle applies, but be warned, that by setting the transistor base current to a fixed value and than expecting the collector current to stay stable is considered a poor design. **This is probably why you found the transistor is dissipating more power as you expected.** The gain was higher than you predicted, so more power was drawn from the battery.

Altough the collector current and base current are tied togather by the gain factor (called Beta for bipolar transistors), the transistor gain is by no means stable and should not be relied on. You can expect about 70% variation, affected by the collector current, temperature and frequency of operation. You must also take into account that the gain differs from batch to batch of manufactured transistors, even from the same factory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really drawing only 0.017 Amp from 12 volts, the transistor and glow plug together will only dissipate 0.2 watts, and will only be slightly (perhaps barely detectably) warm.

According to the TIP122 data sheet, the *minimum* DC current gain is 1000, with no mention of the maximum.  You must have a very high gain transistor, and are drawing much more than your desired 0.017 Amp.

If the glow plug is intended to operate from 12 volts, you should supply enough base current to saturate the transistor.

Comment: I see on the datasheet, on the top right of the Figure 2 it says Ic=250Ib. I'm not really sure what to make of that.

Peter, I sort of wanted to play around with the temperature of the glow plug. I figured I could do this with 12V source and modulating the current by limiting the base pin. 

Perhaps I'm using the wrong component for this.

Comment: As you turn on a transistor really hard, the effect is that the gain drops.  We call this saturation.  When a datasheet says saturation, they need to define what that means, in this case Ic=250Ib is the definition.  So this graph shows you the combination of Vbe(or Vce) vs collector current that you need to pull the hfe down to 250.  As you go beyond that, it will just drop further, but this is the line that they have defined as saturation for this part.